# Calculating the absenteeism improvement for cabin crew

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics

I have the number of monthly flights, and the number of the active cabin crew in monthly basis, and the number of crew who were absence (sick leave or so) in monthly bases as well. How do I get an index or indicator about the absence rate? I want to know are things are improving or not by using all three parameters available. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site. How many months of data do you have? I am guessing you have quite a lot. If so, you probably want some sort of time-series analysis.

The absence rate would be just the number absent divided by the total of the number active and absent. A good first step is to figure that for each month and then graph it over time. That graph could have "Month" on the x-axis and "absence rate" on the y-axis, and then a line.

However, the time series aspects can get involved: There are likely seasonal effects, for example. You could explore those if you have data for a long enough period.

Others here are more expert on time-series than I am, so I will stop here and add the "time-series" tag to attract them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is an important element you have forgot to count in, the number of flights per month.. isn't that important to get the best possible statistics?

Comment: You tell me! Seriously, that is a substantive question, not a statistical one. The absence rate, as far as I can tell, is simple (and that is what you asked for). It is possible that the absence rate **depends** on the number of flights, and you could include that in some models if you are looking to explain the absence rate. At the initial stage I suggested, you could certainly add "number of flights" to the plot.

Comment: Well, if the number of flights are higher then we expect the absence to be higher.. so you suggest to include it somehow to show it only?

Comment: and btw, I have zero knowledge in these things.. so please go easy on me :)

Comment: You need a time series expert.... I am not one. It's a complex area.

Comment: thank you very much Peter. you answer already put me in the right track :)