# Getting the number of active employees per month

Tags: mean

In large companies with thousands of employees, how to get the number of employees per month? everyday there could be new employees, resigned or terminated employees, etc. If I want to get the number of the employees in a given month it will be confusing since the number of employees differs from one day to another in the same month. Do I just calculate the average number (total employee in all days/total days) or can I get the highest and lowest and divide by two? which is better or is there a better and more accurate way?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you need, does it not? What do you need this value for?

Comment: @posdef I need it for this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50615/calculating-the-absenteeism-improvement-for-cabin-crew

Answer (score 2):

Having had a look at the question you have linked to it appears you need the number of employees the firm has so you can estimate the absenteeism rate.  For these purposes I would think the number of staff days divided by the number of days in the month would be the best figure.  Effectively, it gives you the average number of employees on any day in that month, and this would seem the appropriate indicator of the average potential absenteeism in that period.